# Fail2Ban custom filter not applied

Tags: security, fail2ban, antergos

I tried to create a **custom jail rule in fail2ban**, but it never gets applied.

I did not find such an official documentation, I might miss something.

> /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/expressjs.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = .* from ip <HOST>
```

> /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf

```
[express-js]
enabled  = true
filter   = expressjs
logpath  = /var/log/expressjs/slowin-killer.log
maxretry = 5
bantime  = 3600
findtime = 600
```

> /var/log/expressjs/slowin-killer.log

```
[20-5-2017 20:49:57] Failed to authentificate user "dinath.contact@gmail.comdddd" from ip 127.0.0.1
[20-5-2017 20:57:19] Failed to authentificate user "dinath.contact@gmail.comdddd" from ip 127.0.0.1
[20-5-2017 20:59:20] Failed to authentificate user "dinath.contact@gmail.comdddd" from ip 127.0.0.1
[20-5-2017 21:12:47] Failed to authentificate user "dinath.contact@gmail.comdddd" from ip 127.0.0.1
[20-5-2017 21:16:9] Failed to authentificate user "dinath.contact@gmail.comdddd" from ip 127.0.0.1
```

No error message, but the jail seems to be active...

```
$ fail2ban-client status expressjs
Status for the jail: expressjs
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed: 0
|  `- File list:    /var/log/expressjs/slowin-killer.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned: 0
   `- Banned IP list:
```

And the weird thing, regex is ok...

> fail2ban-regex /var/log/expressjs/slowin-killer.log
>   /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/expressjs.conf

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : expressjs, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /var/log/expressjs/slowin-killer.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 27 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [27] .* from ip <HOST>
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [34] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])Month(?P=_sep)(?:Year|Year2) 24hour:Minute:Second
|  [1] (?:DAY )?MON Day Year 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?
`-

Lines: 162 lines, 0 ignored, 27 matched, 135 missed
[processed in 0.01 sec]

Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 135 lines
```

Comment: Maybe an `action =` setting problem. https://serverfault.com/questions/727807/fail2ban-regex-test-succeed-but-fail2ban-does-not-ban-any-ip

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried it :/

Comment: how is configured the IPTable part of your failtoban, looks like your rule is not applied

Answer (score 2):

There are some things that you are missing and need to fix to make the filter work:

1. Inside your `expressjs.conf` you have set `findtime = 600` and `maxretry = 5` This means that in a space of 10 minutes(600s) you will need to have 5 failed tries(regex match) to generate the automatic block/reject iptables rule. `jail.conf` manpage:

> ```
>    findtime
>           time interval (in seconds) before the current time where failures will count towards a ban.
>
>    maxretry
>           number of failures that have to occur in the last findtime seconds to ban then IP.
> ```

Taking a look at your logs, you have more than 10 minutes between 1st log entry and last log entry(5 tries) on the log you pasted here. First: `20:49`, Last:`21:16`

2. All your logs comes from `127.0.0.1`. If you look at your `jail.conf` inside the `[DEFAULT]` block you will find the `ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8` default configuration. Unless you have changed that, it's pretty dangerous to block a localhost address since will break other softwares using this address for internal communication.
3. You `expressjs.conf` does not have the `datepattern =` configuration set so, fail2ban cannot guess what part of the logfile is the date. Get some examples from `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d` files and you will find date regex like `datepattern = ^L %%d/%%m/%%Y - %%H:%%M:%%S` or `datepattern = ^%%Y:%%m:%%d-%%H:%%M:%%S`. Other issue here is that your "second" part of the log date does not have the trailing zero on sec < 10 (ex: `21:16:9` on your last log) and this needs to be fixed.

Take a look at the [Fail2ban official wiki](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to get examples and make your filter better. You have a lot of things to fix.